# How to Show bluetooth Connection status in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bluetooth

I am developing one app. I need to show the status whether device is connected or not to another paired device. I am able to show toast message but am unable to show whether bluetooth is connected to other device or not in the List view.

Can you please look at my added code once and help me in the issue..

my DeviceListActivity.class

```
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    mDeviceList.addAll(pairedDevices);

    mAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(this);

    mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);

    mAdapter.setListener(new OnConnectButtonClickListener() {

        public void onConnectButtonClick(int position) {
            BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);
            ConnectDevice(device);
        }
    });

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    registerReceiver(mConnectReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
    registerReceiver(mConnectReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
     } 

     private void ConnectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {

    try {
        // SERIAL_UUID = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
        // msocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
        msocket = (BluetoothSocket) method.invoke(device, 2);
        msocket.connect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
            msocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeEx) {
            closeEx.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mConnectReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            showToast("BlueTooth is Connected");

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            showToast("BlueTooth DisConnected");

        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mConnectReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My DeviceListAdapter class

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<BluetoothDevice> mData;
private OnConnectButtonClickListener connectListener;

public DeviceListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setData(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
    mData = data;
}

public void setListener(OnConnectButtonClickListener listener) {
    connectListener = listener;
}

public int getCount() {
    return (mData == null) ? 0 : mData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_device, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.nameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        holder.addressTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        holder.connectBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    BluetoothDevice device = mData.get(position);

    holder.nameTv.setText(device.getName());
    holder.addressTv.setText(device.getAddress());
    holder.connectBtn.setText("connect");
    holder.connectBtn.setText("connected");

    holder.connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (connectListener != null) {
                connectListener.onConnectButtonClick(position);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTv;
    TextView addressTv;
    Button connectBtn;
}

public interface OnConnectButtonClickListener {
    public abstract void onConnectButtonClick(int position);

}
```

Now by using register receiver, when click on connect I need to update the status of list item as connected.

Any help in this issue can save my day. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, are you having trouble actually *displaying* the status in the list view, or are you trying to get suggestions on an approach to take to indicate connection?

Comment: yeah, I am having trouble on displaying  the connection status i.e whether connected to or not for each list item in the list.

Comment: Well, have a look at my answer. I think it suits your needs if I understand them.

Comment: @lase, I worked out on your answer, I am not able to get it properly. Can you please make an edit to my  question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to change up how your store your data. `BluetoothDevice` will allow you to check your bonding state with `getBondState()`, but if you take a look at the docs, that won't necessarily help:

> Being bonded (paired) with a remote device does not necessarily mean the device is currently connected. It just means that the pending procedure was completed at some earlier time, and the link key is still stored locally, ready to use on the next connection.

You might want to create a simple wrapper around your `BluetoothDevice` that you can set the connection state on.

```
class BluetoohInfo {
    BluetoothDevice device;
    boolean connected;

    BluetoothInfo(BluetoothDevice device, boolean connected) {
        this.device = device;
        this.connected = connected;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }
    // getters and setters of your choosing
}
```

Now, instead of displaying a `Toast` inside of your `BroadcastReceiver`, just set the connected property of the `BluetoothInfo` to `true`.

Then, make `mDeviceList` a list of `BluetoothInfo`, so that they back your `ListView`, rather than just a raw list of `BluetoothDevice`:

```
mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothInfo>();
```

Inside of `getView()` of your list adapter, do a check for your connected property.

```
if (bluetoothInfo.isConnected()) {
    holder.connectBtn.setText("connected");
} else {
    holder.connectBtn.setText("connect");
}
```

By doing this, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside of your receiver should make these changes effective.